# Get a list of ACF Repeater-Fields as array

Tags: wp-query, advanced-custom-fields, array, list

I run a Site for a concert & music club. Events are set within a custom post type called "events". In this i set the date, the name of the event and all other infos about that event.

In this custom post type, I have a ACF (advanced custom fields) Repeater called "artists", with the subfields "artistname" and "artistweb".

My goal is al list of artists, played in our club in the past. This list should be alphabetically sorted by artistname, and if a link (artistlik) exists, the name of the artist shoul be linked to that site.

**What I have so far:**

```
<?php
// find todays date
$today = date('Ymd');

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    'post_type'     => 'artists',
    'meta_query'    => array(
        'relation'      => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'date',
            'value' => $today,
            'compare' => '<',
        ),
    )
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
$post_ids = wp_list_pluck( $the_query->posts, 'ID' );
$artist_list = array();

foreach($post_ids as $post_id){
    $artist_repeater = get_field('artists', $post_id);

    if (is_array($artist_repeater)) {
        foreach($artist_repeater as $artist_detail){
            array_push($artist_list, $artist_detail);
        }
    }
}

$artist_list = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $artist_list)));
$order = array();
foreach( $artist_list as $i => $row ) {
    $order[ $i ] = $row['artistname'];
}

array_multisort( $order, SORT_ASC, $artist_list );
echo "<pre>";
print_r($artist_list);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

That works half the way!

With the above code I get all artistnames and artistwebsites, but the look like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [artistname] => 7th Break
        [artistweb] => 
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [artistname] => Al Berto & the Fried Bikinis
        [artistweb] => http://www.al-berto.ch
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [artistname] => Asskick
        [artistweb] => 
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [artistname] => Aynsley Lister
        [artistweb] => www.aynsleylister.co.uk
    )
.........
```

My goal is just a normal ul list with artistnames, and if an artists have a link the name should be linked to that url

- 7th Break
- Al Berto & the Fried Bikinis
- Asskick
- Aynsley Lister

Does anyone can give me some help?

Thank you

Roman

Answer (score 1):

Holy loop attack Batman! I think you can simplify this a lot:

```
$the_posts = get_posts( array(
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    'post_type'      => 'artists',
    'meta_query'     => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'     => 'date',
            'value'   => date( 'Ymd' ),
            'compare' => '<',
        ),
    )
));

$the_list = array();

foreach ( $the_posts as $the_post ) {
    if ( $artists = get_field( 'artists', $the_post->ID ) ) {
        // Build a simple name => link index
        foreach ( $artists as $artist )
            $the_list[ $artist['artistname'] ] = $artist['artistweb'];
    }
}

// Now sort the array by key (artist name)
ksort( $the_list );

echo '<ul>';
foreach ( $the_list as $artist => $link ) {
    echo '<li>';
        if ( $link )
            echo '<a href="' . $link . '">';

        echo $artist;

        if ( $link )
            echo '</a>';
    echo '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: I would first make sure that we have posts before trying to loop through them :-)